# Populate my textboxes with my entity framework

Tags: c#

is it possible to populate my textboxes this way? 
Receiving an error at select “Cannot implicitly convert type system.Linq.Querable”

Basically I’m trying to make one all to the database, then use this connection to populate the rest of my textboxes on the web form.

Any help or pointers much appreciated.

```
  private void Loadorder()
        {
            using (tyrescannerdatabaseEntities dbcontext = new tyrescannerdatabaseEntities())

               query = (from Orders in dbcontext.Orders

                        join customer in dbcontext.Customers on Orders.CustomerID equals customer.CustomerID

                        join link_orderproduct in dbcontext.Link_OrderProduct on Orders.OrderID equals link_orderproduct.OrderID

                        join product in dbcontext.Products on link_orderproduct.ProductID equals product.ProductID

                        join garage in dbcontext.Garages on link_orderproduct.GarageID equals garage.GarageID

                         where Orders.OrderID == orderId.Value

                         select new DataMode
                         {
                         OrderID = Orders.OrderID,
                         Name = customer.Name
                         };


    private void SetControlsWithRecord()
    {
        txtOrderID.Text = query.OrderID.ToString();
        txtCustomer.Text = query.Customer.Name.ToString();
    }

 class DataMode
{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ContactNo { get; set; }
    public string Registration { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string TyreModel { get; set; }
    public decimal Width { get; set; }
    public string Profile { get; set; }
    public string Diamete { get; set; }
    public string Speed { get; set; }
    public string FittingDate { get; set; }
    public decimal ProductUnitSalePrice { get; set; }
    public string ProductQuantity { get; set; }
    public string TotalProductSaleCost { get; set; }
    public string MOT { get; set; }
    public string AirConRecharge { get; set; }
    public string WheelTracking { get; set; }
    public string MOTS { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
query = (from Orders in dbcontext.Orders

                    join customer in dbcontext.Customers on Orders.CustomerID equals customer.CustomerID

                    join link_orderproduct in dbcontext.Link_OrderProduct on Orders.OrderID equals link_orderproduct.OrderID

                    join product in dbcontext.Products on link_orderproduct.ProductID equals product.ProductID

                    join garage in dbcontext.Garages on link_orderproduct.GarageID equals garage.GarageID

                     where Orders.OrderID == orderId.Value

                     select new DataMode
                     {
                     OrderID = Orders.OrderID,
                     Name = customer.Name
                     }).ToList();
```

add this `ToList()` at the end of the query. And remove it from here

```
txtOrderID.Text = query.OrderID.ToString();
    txtCustomer.Text = query.Customer.Name.ToString();
```

Comment: receiving error next ToList() - Create a system.Collection Generic list<T>

I'm new to c# still learning, I have no idea how to address this..

Comment: Are you using linq to query or ado.net data entity to work with the database or anything else?

Comment: I'm just using linq, would I be better off just using a SP?

Comment: wait. i try to make a solution for you... but i want to know how you connect to the database

Comment: I'm using Entity framework using (tyrescannerdatabaseEntities dbcontext = new tyrescannerdatabaseEntities())

Comment: can i contact you with email cuz the answer will be long and can change from the needs

Comment: yep, brucey54@hotmail.com